# simple nested conditional statement in perl

Tags: perl, conditional-statements

I think I'm missing something, as I would say the below should print MATCH.

```
($one,$two)=(220,219);
print "MATCH" if (($one or $one+1 or $one-1) == ($two or $two+1 or $two-1));
```

Can't find an easy explanation why I don't see MATCH printed.
Is there another way to simply test for the above condition?

Comment: It doesn't print "MATCH" because they are not equal. Trying printing out `($one or $one+1 or $one-1)` and `($two or $two+1 or $two-1)`

Comment: That's correct. Somehow I thought perl will match each $one from first brackets with every $two from the other brackets. Nevertheless thanks for your help.

Comment: It doesn't actually match each one against the other, it only evaluates the first one since it is a TRUE value and `220 != 219`, I have explained in more detail below.

Comment: @mjp No, if you want that behaviour, you have to code it explicitly. Smart matching `~~` has that functionality, but then smart matching is all but deprecated.

Comment: This is also explained in [perlfaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays?-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logical or (e.g `or`) is a [short-circuiting operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) which means that in a statement like

```
A or B
```

B will only be evaluated if A is FALSE.

In your statement above:

```
($one or $one+1 or $one-1)
```

The value contained in the variable `$one` is TRUE (because it is != 0) so the value of `$one` is returned, which is `220`.

```
($two or $two+1 or $two-1)
```

The value contained in the variable `$two` is TRUE (because it is != 0) so the value of `$two` is returned, which is `219`.

`220 == 219` is FALSE, so `"MATCH"` is not printed.

Comment: @mjp If you are happy with the answers, you can mark one of them as accepted by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

You test doesn't work because each parenthesis return always the first true assertion (i.e. the value of `$one` for the first and the value of `$two` for the second)

You can try something like this:

```
print "MATCH" if (abs($one-$two)<3)
```

Note: this works only with integers.

Comment: Thanks. That is one quick way to test it.